# data overwrited when added to Json Array

Tags: java, json

I have data coming from Splunk, the data are host with ports, some host have more then one port. so I made the logic below. for every host with single port I added to jsonarray. the issue is the port is always overwrite at the moment where it added to the jsonarray I counldnt figure out why?

````
 public JSONObject parse_OS_Vuln_data_to_Json() {
        JSONObject responseDetailsJson = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        if (list_of_OS_VulnerabilityOS.size()>0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < list_of_OS_VulnerabilityOS.size(); i++) {
                JSONObject formDetailsJson = new JSONObject();
                if (list_of_OS_VulnerabilityOS.get(i).getList_of_ports().size() > 1)
                {
                    for (int v = 0; v < list_of_OS_VulnerabilityOS.get(i).getList_of_ports().size(); v++)
                    {
                        formDetailsJson.put("host", list_of_OS_VulnerabilityOS.get(i).getDest());
                        formDetailsJson.put("port", list_of_OS_VulnerabilityOS.get(i).getList_of_ports().get(v)); // i got each time different port 
                        formDetailsJson.put("open", list_of_OS_VulnerabilityOS.get(i).isOpen());
                        formDetailsJson.put("info", list_of_OS_VulnerabilityOS.get(i).getInfo()); 
                        jsonArray.add(formDetailsJson); // here it overwrites to the first port again  
                        total_hostNumber_OS++;
                    }
                } else {
                    formDetailsJson.put("host", list_of_OS_VulnerabilityOS.get(i).getDest());
                    formDetailsJson.put("port", list_of_OS_VulnerabilityOS.get(i).getPorts___port());
                    formDetailsJson.put("open", list_of_OS_VulnerabilityOS.get(i).isOpen());
                    formDetailsJson.put("info", list_of_OS_VulnerabilityOS.get(i).getInfo());
                    jsonArray.add(formDetailsJson);
                    total_hostNumber_OS++;
                }
        }
            responseDetailsJson.put("data", jsonArray);
            System.out.print("\n list size: " + list_of_OS_VulnerabilityOS.size());
            System.out.print("\n total of OS-host to be send : " + total_hostNumber_OS);

        }
        return responseDetailsJson;
    }```
````

Comment: Use different keys  when you itterate over an array. if you use the same key, it is normal that data is overwritten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're referencing the same formDetailsJson instance within your 'v'-loop. Meaning that every time you call 'put', it's on the same object (This means that not only your port should be overwritten, but all other fields as well). All entries in your jsonArray would be a reference to the same instance.

It might also be nicer to assign a variable to list_of_OS_VulnerabilityOS inside of your loop instead of duplicating so often.

Code would look something like this:

```java
    public JSONObject parse_OS_Vuln_data_to_Json() {
        JSONObject responseDetailsJson = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        if (list_of_OS_VulnerabilityOS.size()>0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < list_of_OS_VulnerabilityOS.size(); i++) {
                WhateverTheTypeIs currentOSVulnerability = list_of_OS_VulnerabilityOS.get(i);
                JSONObject formDetailsJson;

                if (currentOSVulnerability .getList_of_ports().size() > 1) {
                    for (int v = 0; v < list_of_OS_VulnerabilityOS.get(i).getList_of_ports().size(); v++) {
                        formDetailsJson = new JSONObject() // Here's the fix: assign inside of the loop, so it's a new instance
                        formDetailsJson.put("host", currentOSVulnerability.getDest());
                        formDetailsJson.put("port", currentOSVulnerability.getList_of_ports().get(v));
                        formDetailsJson.put("open", currentOSVulnerability.isOpen());
                        formDetailsJson.put("info", currentOSVulnerability.getInfo());
                        jsonArray.add(formDetailsJson);
                        total_hostNumber_OS++;
                    }
                } else {
                    formDetailsJson = new JSONObject();
                    formDetailsJson.put("host", currentOSVulnerability.getDest());
                    formDetailsJson.put("port", currentOSVulnerability.getPorts___port());
                    formDetailsJson.put("open", currentOSVulnerability.isOpen());
                    formDetailsJson.put("info", currentOSVulnerability.getInfo());
                    jsonArray.add(formDetailsJson);
                    total_hostNumber_OS++;
                }
            }
            responseDetailsJson.put("data", jsonArray);
            System.out.print("\n list size: " + list_of_OS_VulnerabilityOS.size());
            System.out.print("\n total of OS-host to be send : " + total_hostNumber_OS);
        }
        return responseDetailsJson;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public JSONObject parse_OS_Vuln_data_to_Json() {
    JSONObject responseDetailsJson = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    if (list_of_OS_VulnerabilityOS.size()>0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list_of_OS_VulnerabilityOS.size(); i++) {
            JSONObject formDetailsJson = null; // change #1
            if (list_of_OS_VulnerabilityOS.get(i).getList_of_ports().size() > 1)
            {
                for (int v = 0; v < list_of_OS_VulnerabilityOS.get(i).getList_of_ports().size(); v++)
                {
                    formDetailsJson = new JSONObject();  // change #2
                    formDetailsJson.put("host", list_of_OS_VulnerabilityOS.get(i).getDest());
                    formDetailsJson.put("port", list_of_OS_VulnerabilityOS.get(i).getList_of_ports().get(v)); // i got each time different port 
                    formDetailsJson.put("open", list_of_OS_VulnerabilityOS.get(i).isOpen());
                    formDetailsJson.put("info", list_of_OS_VulnerabilityOS.get(i).getInfo()); 
                    jsonArray.add(formDetailsJson); // here it overwrites to the first port again  
                    total_hostNumber_OS++;
                }
            } else {
                formDetailsJson = new JSONObject();  // change #3
                formDetailsJson.put("host", list_of_OS_VulnerabilityOS.get(i).getDest());
                formDetailsJson.put("port", list_of_OS_VulnerabilityOS.get(i).getPorts___port());
                formDetailsJson.put("open", list_of_OS_VulnerabilityOS.get(i).isOpen());
                formDetailsJson.put("info", list_of_OS_VulnerabilityOS.get(i).getInfo());
                jsonArray.add(formDetailsJson);
                total_hostNumber_OS++;
            }
    }
        responseDetailsJson.put("data", jsonArray);
        System.out.print("\n list size: " + list_of_OS_VulnerabilityOS.size());
        System.out.print("\n total of OS-host to be send : " + total_hostNumber_OS);

    }
    return responseDetailsJson;
}
```

In the #2 for loop, you are using the same formDetailsJson object. So each time the loop runs, your formDetailsJson object would be overwrited.